# Assign field value to attribute in ABAP ST transformation?

Tags: xml, abap-st

I'm using SAP Simple Transformation and I want to set value of `unitCode` attribute from ABAP field which is defined inside my structure. Let's say it's `UNITCODE` field.

```
 <cbc:InvoicedQuantity tt:value-ref="INVOICEDQUANTITY" unitCode="C62" unitCodeListID="UNECRec20"/>
```

Right now `unitCode` is hardcoded as value `C62` but I want that this attribute takes value from ABAP `UNITCODE` field (in same structure as `INVOICEDQUANTITY`). How can I make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed `xslt` from the title and from the tags, because your question is about SAP Simple Transformation, not XSLT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may initialize an attribute from an ABAP variable using [`tt:attribute`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenst_tt_attribute.htm):

```
  <cbc:InvoicedQuantity tt:value-ref="INVOICEDQUANTITY" unitCodeListID="UNECRec20">
    <tt:attribute name="unitCode" value-ref="UNITCODE"/>
  </cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
```

Below is a Minimal Reproducible Example:

- ABAP :

  ```
  DATA : BEGIN OF ls_data,
           invoicedquantity TYPE decfloat34,
           unitcode         TYPE string,
         END OF ls_data.
  ls_data = VALUE #( invoicedquantity = 1000 unitcode = 'C62' ).
  CALL TRANSFORMATION ztransfo
      SOURCE abaproot = ls_data
      RESULT XML DATA(xml).
  ```
- Simple Transformation `ZTRANSFO`:

  ```
  <?sap.transform simple?>
  <tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates"
        xmlns:ddic="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/dictionary">
    <tt:root name="ABAPROOT"/>
    <tt:template>
    <ROOT xmlns:cbc="http://xxx" tt:ref="ABAPROOT">
      <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCodeListID="UNECRec20">
        <tt:attribute name="unitCode" value-ref="UNITCODE"/>
        <tt:value ref="INVOICEDQUANTITY"/>
      </cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    </ROOT>
    </tt:template>
  </tt:transform>
  ```
- Expected XML result:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ROOT xmlns:cbc="http://xxx">
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCodeListID="UNECRec20" unitCode="C62">
      1000
    </cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  </ROOT>
  ```

Comment: I checked your solution, set it like this: 
```<cbc:InvoicedQuantity tt:value-ref="INVOICEDQUANTITY" unitCodeListID="UNECRec20">
            <tt:attribute name="unitCode" value-ref="UNITCODE"/>
          </cbc:InvoicedQuantity>```
When I'm trying to activate it, prints an error in ```<tt:attribute>``` line. Error msg:
"Content of element wasn't expected" (something like this)

Comment: Hmm. You're right, I didn't test my solution. I've got the error `unknown root name 'INVOICEDQUANTITY' ` -> solved by adding the root (`tt:ref="ABAPROOT"`) and then `expected no element content` because `tt:value-ref` is not authorized if the node has some content, here an attribute -> solved by moving it after `<tt:attribute.../>` as `<tt:value ref="..."/>`.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
unitCode="C62"
```

you can use:

```
unitCode="{UnitCode}"
```

or more precisely:

```
unitCode="{path/to/UnitCode}"
```

where `path/to/UnitCode` is the path to the `UnitCode` element from the context of the current node.

Comment: For information, the OP did a mistake. It's about a SAP Simple Transformation (because of `tt:value-ref`), not XSLT.